# Why is $watch not updating when the model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is the watch not logging every time the model changes?

Why is the Input not beginning with the value test?

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';


    // Create the application.
    var app = angular.module('tabApplication', []);

    // Creat the tabs controller.
    app.controller('tabController', ['$log', '$scope', function ($log, $scope) {
        $scope.myName = 'test';
        $log.log($scope.myName);
        
        $scope.$watch('myName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $log.log(newValue, oldValue); 
        });


    }]);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="tabApplication" ng-controller="tabController as tabC">
 <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="tabC.myName"></p>
 <h1>Hello {{tabC.myName}}</h1>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried watching the string `'tabC.myName'` instead of juste watching `'myName'`:

```
$scope.$watch('tabC.myName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $log.log(newValue, oldValue); 
});
```

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's good to have someone with a fresh look on your code ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-model="tabC.myName"` is not binding to the `$scope.myName` variable, that is why the input appears empty at the begining and not with 'test'.

try `ng-model="myName"` instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

As [cl3m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35395791/5267669) answer pointed since you are using controller as syntax you have to watch for 'tabC.myName'

Another way to do it and stay to the controller as paradigm (i.e. have the controller be a constructor) is using `this` for setting the variables, and importing `$scope` to use the `$watch` functionality

```
(function () {
    'use strict';


    // Create the application.
    var app = angular.module('tabApplication', []);

    // Creat the tabs controller.
    app.controller('tabController', ['$log', '$scope', function ($log, $scope) {
        this.myName = 'test';
        $log.log(this.myName);

        $scope.$watch('tabC.myName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $log.log(newValue, oldValue); 
        });


    }]);
}());
```